# Reading .txt file

Tags: vb.net

I am using following code to read text from a .txt file.  But I don't know how to 
perform search within file and how to read a specific line in the text file, based on search.

```
Dim vrDisplay = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(CurDir() & "\keys.txt")
    MsgBox(vrDisplay)
```

For an example,

if I want to read the line that contains the word "Start", how to do that

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of reading all text, for efficiency's sake,

- Open a FileStream for the file in question.
- Create a StreamReader.
- Loop through, calling ReadLine until either you find the end of the file, or the string contains "Start".

---

Edit: even if it's required that you keep the entire file in memory, you can still do the above by using a `MemoryStream()`.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't easy to tell from your post if it's the best possible solution, but one solution would be to use [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info) to find all lines containing the word `Start`:

```
^.*\bStart\b.*$
```

matches an entire line that contains the complete word `Start` anywhere. It rejects `Start` as a part of a word, for example `Starting` won't be matched (that's what the `\b` word boundary anchors are for).

To use this in VB.NET:

```
Dim RegexObj As New Regex(
    "^      # Start of line" & chr(10) & _
    ".*     # Any number of characters (anything except newlines)" & chr(10) & _
    "\b     # Word boundary" & chr(10) & _
    "Start  # ""Start""" & chr(10) & _
    "\b     # Word boundary" & chr(10) & _
    ".*     # Any number of characters (anything except newlines)" & chr(10) & _
    "$      # End of line", 
    RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
AllMatchResults = RegexObj.Matches(vrDisplay)
If AllMatchResults.Count > 0 Then
    ' Access individual matches using AllMatchResults.Item[]
Else
    ' Match attempt failed
End If
```

Comment: Would probably work, but a built-in StreamReader.ReadLine() would probably be faster and require less memory than running a regex on a string containing the entire file.

Comment: @Reinderien: Exactly. But perhaps he needs the entire file in memory at once. Who can tell?